# Bounties that expire with no answer

Tags: support, bounty

What happens if a bounty expires, but the question still has no answers?

Comment: You need more than this statement from the FAQ? "A bounty does not guarantee a response, however, and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty."

Comment: @Louis I suppose it does, but it's easy to miss...

Comment: What if a competition ends and no one participated in it. What happens to the grand prize?

Comment: @AzizShaikh In theory, the competition organiser just [keeps the prize](http://xkcd.com/570/) - obviously not what happens with bounties here ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Stack Exchange keeps the bounty reps in this case :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Hey come on, they have to feed the unicorns somehow...

Comment: And the real question that comes to my mind is that: Why doesn't the bounty reward back to the asker when there is no answer ??!

Comment: (This is a little old school, but...) When you place an ad in the newspaper to sell your Pokemon card collection, but no one responds, the newspaper doesn't refund your money. That's essentially what a bounty is.

Comment: newspaper logic seems irrelevant when offering your own reputation points is called Bounty and not Ad. If goal of this page is providing answers to questions, I would expect that you do not loose the points so you can always offer more

Comment: I agree with @JanHruby because newspaper ads means money, newspaper company running on money but is that stackoverflow running on reputation. In other word what is the point of destroying reputation thats earned by effort of someone.

Comment: The justification here and in the FAQ seem to relate SE bounties to advertising. I tend to associate the word "bounty" with a reward, which would be transferred when the task is successfully completed. Now that I have read the FAQ, it makes sense, but it wasn't intuitive and perhaps a better name could have avoided some misunderstanding.

Comment: Maybe they're thinking of converting SE rep into a crypto-currency ;)

Comment: I have put a few bounties to some questions that got no answers. But interestingly, I always got my reputation back. I wonder why that was, if they were supposedly non-refundable.

Comment: Can someone know if we can't give reputation to yourself ? Like self-answer and accept it ?

Comment: @Elikill58 The FAQ answers that one too: "You cannot award a bounty to your own answer."

Comment: @JohnMontgomery oh thanks I didn't see it

Comment: @ale: The newspaper ad analogy is really broken. When you place an ad in the newspaper to sell your Pokemon card collection, and someone does buy it, then the buyer does not receive the money, either. That's because the money paid for the ad was always meant for the newspaper, as a fee to publish the ad. A bounty, in contrast, is meant for the person answering the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You're paying the platform for the visibility and to attract users to the question.  Part of that attraction is the possibility of being awarded the bounty, but the visibility and attraction occur regardless of whether the bounty is awarded to anyone.  The service of attracting the users is performed regardless of whether an answer is received.

Comment: @RyanM: I'm not paying *the platform*, because rep is valuable to me as a user, but worthless to the platform. At the same time, "visibility and attraction" on their own are irrelevant to me unless they culminate in answers. You could also argue "the service of attracting the users" was not successfully performed. In any case, I'm paying something, somewhere, the purpose of which seems to be to give me an incentive for a certain behaviour. For instance, an incentive could be that if I offer a bounty, and other users make the effort to write an answer, I should not break my "promise" and ...

Comment: ... keep the bounty rep for myself instead of awarding it to one of the answering users. But what is the incentive that I'm supposed to get when I lose my rep because I *could not* award it to any answer? Avoid using bounties in the future? Only ask about simple problems that many users could answer?

Comment: Quite some people think that, when a bountied question gets no answer, then the bounty should be paid back. I agree on that statement. However, this might cause people to put bounties on every one of their questions, which is obviously not the aim of the bounties. In order to avoid such behaviour, is some kind of penalty foresee for people who put bounties but don't reward anyone?

Comment: Here's my take on why bounties should not be returned: If the bounty was returned, it could be re-offered indefinitely. In this case, it doesn't make sense to have it run out in the first place (assuming the offering person isn't trying to implement a round-robin mechanism). But if a bounty is available forever, then answering "now" is not time-critical anymore. The ephemeral nature of a bounty is (in theory) what drives a person that would go "I could probably figure that out" to actually invest the time *here and now*. With full refund, that bit would go away.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The FAQ *does* answer what happens when a bounty expires but the question has no answers:

> If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Combined with:

> **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

at the top, it should be painfully obvious that when there are no answers, and the bounty *already paid up front*, the bounty simply goes *pop*.

Comment: No refund to the owner? :(

Comment: Though this policy is clear, it is also pretty ridiculous. Why would you not give the person who asked the question a refund on their points if the question was well received (highly upvoted) but received no answer? Also, it is a very non-intuitive policy. Why would you expect a bounty to disappear into thin air if nobody claims it?

Comment: @DIMMSum: because a bounty is **advertising**, not a warranty. When you place an ad in the paper for your new mousetrap, all you'll know is that people will see the ad, there is no guarantee people will buy the product (*or your money back!*).

Comment: @MartijnPieters true, but I don't really think it's in the spirit of the site. Should your "reputation" that you've built up from contributing to the community be penalized because nobody else in the community could help you for a question? It also discourages people from putting up bounties. I guess I just don't see any reason for the policy being this way.

Comment: Is that "pop" audible?

Comment: @matt: the server admins have to wear hearing protection whenever they are working on the hardware, in case of unawarded bounties going 'pop'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that `advertising` argument is really ridiculous IMO. Rep is not a currency in the sense of an mag advert. I would understand it if the rep is not refunded if there are answers but none is accepeted, because the system can not know if the asker tries to cheat or if the answers were useless. Would maybe need a moderator to clear it. If there are no answers, then the rep should go back. It's more like `I pay anybody who can bring me the answer dead or alive` but if nobody ever shows up there is nobody I could give the money and thus it stays with me.

Comment: No refunds makes sense to me. If you get your reputation back, users would game this. e.g. I could put 500 rep on every one of my questions from now on and never accept any of the answers to my question or pay out the bounty...

Comment: @Devolus: you are not doing the advertising however. You pay the site to do the advertising. It's exactly like paying Google for adverts when people search for something. Showing an ad doesn't mean that anyone will actually click the link or buy your product. You can shout out your own window about your award, but *no-one on the site would know about it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I guess this can be viewed differently as well. Rep has no inherent value to the site, so it's not as if you are really "paying the site". It's more like pinning up a paper on the supermarket black board (which is free to use) saying "I need X and pay Y for it". The supermarket gets not share. Just like stackoverflow also does not get a share. Or what do you think that stackoverflow does with all that uncollected rep it "got payed" with? There is no payment against stackoverflow.

Comment: @Devolus: yet that's not how this works. The supermarket will not make the board more visible to shoppers in the relevant isles, while questions with bounties get special billing on the site. And if rep has no inherent value as you say, **why do you care so much about that you want it back**?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I said it doesn't have (much) value for the site. Certainly not on the scale of some "payment" value. For the user it might be different.

Comment: For me I will be more confident in the use of bounties if they weren't going to expire. I understand why you cannot take the rep back. But atleast mantain the bounty (even if you don't advertise it anymore). Just mantain it as a hidden bounty or something. If I put 50 rep in a question (which is a lot for me since I have less than 600 rep) at least I want somebody to get it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The supermarket does make the board visible. No, it's not that intelligent a system that it would target individual shoppers with individual ads from the board, but that's not a crucial difference IMO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Also, I don't think the claim that "rep has no inherent value" was made as a general statement. Rep has no value to the site, so investing rep cannot be seen as a payment. However, rep does have significant value for users on the site - in particular, because it is limited and therefore acts as a way to cap how much bounty can be offered by a user.

Comment: @Ryan.Bartsch: "I could put 500 rep on every one of my questions from now on and never accept any of the answers to my question" - the discussion here concerns specifically the case where your question did not receive any answers. It is completely ok for the bounty rep to vanish if there has been at least one answer, but the asker decided against awarding the bounty to that answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper there's been multiple times where I've answered a question (only because there was a bounty) and then the bounty has not been awarded. Here's an example from just the other day - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056123/logstash-very-low-throughput-with-rabbitmq/76102670#answer-76102670 IMO this should probably be moderated, if the moderator thinks there's at least one reasonable candidate answer, they should not be refunded their points.

Comment: @Ryan.Bartsch: Ok, but as I wrote, that is beside the point. It is completely ok if the asker loses the bounty rep in that situation. The case discussed here is a different one, namely that there were no answers at all, so the asker *could not* award the bounty to any of them. It is in *that* specific situation where I, and others in this and similar threads, argue the asker should be refunded their points.

Comment: I don't think it actually goes *pop*. I think the community bot steals them.

Answer (score 6):

You have to pay for a bounty upfront, and no refunds are possible, according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Why is that? This is a really bad rule. If nobody answers you should be able get the bounty back... Stackoverflow change this...

Answer (score 1):

If you [delete a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406482/19123103) that you had previously started bounty on, you get your reputation points back.

There's [a section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067) on a Meta SE Q/A about this:

> #### What happens if a question where I awarded a bounty later gets deleted or migrated?
>
> If a question on which you have started or awarded a bounty on later
> gets deleted, then in most cases, your reputation is refunded. It can
> take a few minutes for this to happen. If the question is later
> undeleted or migration is rejected, the reputation is deducted again.
> [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172556)

Comment: This covers questions that have an **awarded** bounty - by default questions without answers cannot have an answer that was awarded the bounty.

In addition: "Update: As of February 13, 2018, the bounty reputation is no longer refunded upon question deletion if the bounty awardee gets to retain it (because it scored +3 and was visible for at least 60 days)."

Comment: @CharonX it says “started _or_ awarded”. Anyway, the part where it is refunded if you delete is still true though, I’ve seen it happen, like in the meta question linked.