# Bounty should be awarded to accepted answer if it expires failing the criteria

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty, accepted-answer

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52433220/6663095) that was asked by a user with a bounty of 100 reps. I noticed and answered it in its grace period. The user accepted the answer after the grace period. Since my answer didn't have enough upvotes and was not accepted at the time of expiry I was not awarded auto bounty. The question also didn't have any other answers at that time. So according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270343/6663095) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56299) I understand the reasons for the same. But, If the criteria is not met to award auto bounty, then the bounty should be awarded at least to the accepted answer post-expiry. The user who spent reps in form of bounty hopes for an answer and the user who answers it hopes to gain it. Now, in this case, why should we waste it?

Comment: Down-votes on meta are not the same as the main site. On meta, they generally mean disagreement with what is being said.

Comment: With `feature-requests`, downvotes express disagreement with the request. Read more about votes on meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: It already works that way.  Problem was that the user accepted the answer long after the bounty and grace period expired.  it ended at 11:00, the accept was at 15:40.  Presumably because there wasn't enough time left to re-check the edited answer, sleep tends to get in the way :)

Comment: Yeah I agree that but the time period should be given to the system to make decision in such cases.

Comment: @Mani And they should call it the Grace Period.   That would make sense, right?

Comment: Yeah, But in this case, my work went in vain right? Anyways bounty is wasted. But why shouldn't it be spent the right/useful way?

Comment: Mani, where's the cutoff though? What you basically suggest is to never have the grace period end. OP missed it by 4h40, you want it extended to that.... if someone misses by 6h00, do we extend it to 6? What about a day? A week?  Also, your answer netted you 25 rep.... you'll get more over time. You've helped the OP, your answer will help others in the future. Don't see it as wasted :)

Comment: I'm trying to check why can't the bounty reps holded untill it meets [these criteias?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270343/6663095) anyays its paid upfront.

Comment: @Mani because that is not a bounty. A bounty is "advertisement", it isn't "the question is now worth X more rep". It wasn't designed this way, it wasn't intended this way. There's a time incentive. Because if you always keep it opened.. what happens if I answer with a great answer, get the bounty, then you come in with a better, **excellent** answer? do you get the bounty? it introduces a layer of complexity to a previously simple system

Comment: I'm the person who ask the question, i'm very sorry for this situation. I didn't see that my bounty was already in grace period :( BUT, i think people "who ask question with a bounty" could always give the bounty, at anytime, even after the grace period end. I don't understand why it's not possible, and this is probably not the first time ...

Comment: hey @reyman64 no hard feelings. I thought of just to understand the reason for designing the logic behind bounty after grace period.

Comment: @Mani again, the bounty is an ad in the paper. You pay for the visibility for a certain time. I'm not saying your idea is necessarily wrong.... but it's just now how the feature was thought of, or intended. It may change, but the change has other implications that may need to be considered in a full feature request

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your answer was not eligible for the bounty. [The bounty period was already over by the time the grace period started](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) — the grace period is to give the bounty setter time to consider the answers that have been posted up until then for the purposes of manually awarding the bounty if they so choose.

The fact that the asker ended up not accepting your answer until after the grace period was over is unfortunate, but it's hard to make a case for automatically awarding a bounty after the setter has already been given a grace period to an answer that was posted during the grace period to begin with.

Comment: But the user is willing to award the bounty after the expiry which he expressed later in comments.

Comment: @Mani: Sounds like they've misunderstood the concept of expiry, and a grace period, then. The moment a bounty expires, it's gone forever. You're supposed to award the bounty *before* it expires, not after.

Comment: So, Now I can't claim bounty even though I worked for it. :-(

Comment: @Mani: But you didn't work for it. The bounty period was over *before* your post was made. You may have thought that you were working for it, but this was an unfortunate mistake on your part.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: There's the possibility of having worked *overtime* for it, of course, in which case then it becomes an issue of time management (something I'm actively dealing with as I write this comment... and being here right now is probably not helping my case).