# Why wasn't the bounty award set after OP acception?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I answered a bounty question with a 500 reputation points award, more than two people upvoted me, and automatically I earned half of the award; that is 250.

After a few days after the end of bounty limitation the post owner marked my answer as the true answer, but I didn't get the remaining bounty. I read and read several times [the Stack Overflow bounty policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). I cannot understand; the post owner accepts my answer, so why shouldn't I get the 250 remaining bounty?

Comment: Because the post owner accepted your answer, but never gave you the bounty? You can do one without the other... it's weird he did, but you can

Comment: Accepting the answer and awarding the bounty are separate actions the OP can take. From the software’s perspective, they’re completely independent. To get the full bounty, the OP has to manually award that bounty to your answer (which is a different button than accepting the answer), **during the period where the bounty is open**. Sounds like in your case, OP missed that window; he didn’t come back to his Q until the bounty had already expired and the “award half automatically” rules kicked in. There is no way now, none at all, for you to get the other 250 pts. They’re gone forever.

Comment: @Patrice, He told me, I didn't check `StackOverflow` for several days, and then when checking his post, see my answer and accept it as a true answer, and unfortunately, I lost 250 reps :( that is not fair, and that does not happen twice for anybody.

Comment: How is it not fair? The OP knew how much time he had for the bounty. The rules are clear and the same for everyone. The fact he didn't check stack is his mistake.... Has nothing to do with fairness.  (And you didn't lose 250 reps. You got 250 reps less than you could have)

Comment: @Patrice, So thanks dear friend for your answer, But everytime I think to the remained 250 reps, I tell myself, It could be yours and just because of the PO fault you lost it.

Comment: Don't fret so much over 250 points. You still earned a very substantial bounty.

Comment: @DanBron, Thanks for your answer. I realize that I cannot gain the remained 250 refs.

Comment: @yivi, Thanks dude, yes, I got the half of bounty that is not very low.

Comment: Indeed, that is indeed what happened. I don't see how saying it's unfair will help though. It's an unfortunate situation. but you still got 8 upvotes, and 250 rep for this answer. It's pretty good for one answer. (and if your answer is truly good... you'll keep getting upvotes trickling in over time)

Comment: @Patrice, Thanks a lot for your word to warm my heart.

Comment: BTW, in English, the abbreviation is *OP* (not *PO*) for *Original Poster*.

Comment: @DanBron, I thought it is _Post Owner_, because of it I think it is _PO_.

Comment: @AmerllicA That’s reasonable, and nothing wrong with it, but that’s not how people use it. It will be easier for people to understand you if you use *OP*, because it is the more common term.

Comment: @DanBron, Thanks for your guide.

Comment: Looks like this is the same case as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375208/bounty-should-be-awarded-to-accepted-answer-if-it-expires-failing-the-criterias People need to be more responsible with their bounties, otherwise answerers like you lose out through no fault of your own. Sorry this happened to you.

Comment: @BoltClock, So thanks for your answer.

Comment: You mean comment. Answers are posted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for bounties are clear: the full bounty needs to be awarded by the user that posted the bounty. If the bounty poster doesn't award it, half is awarded to the highest scoring answer posted after the bounty was offered when the score is at least 2.

If the answer that fulfills this criteria is also accepted, then the full bounty is awarded. So the acceptance of the answer only awards you the full bounty if you also fulfill the other criteria. By itself the accepted vote doesn't assure you that you would also get the full bounty.