# Why was my bounty returned after I deleted the question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, reputation, bounty

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729215/implementing-checkbox-based-view-filtering-in-asp-net-core-mvc) question about a week ago (which apparently, wasn't well-received, but that's another story) and had started a 50-reputation bounty. After the question remained unanswered, and just kept on receiving downvotes, I deleted the question after the bounty ended. However, I found that after I deleted the question, I was returned 52 reputation (50 from the bounty and 2 from god knows where). Was this an intended action?

When I flagged for moderator action, I received the following reply which suggested that it might be a bug:

[image: The flag is marked as helpful and the mod response says the devs are looking into it.]

Comment: The section *What happens if a bounty question is closed or deleted? / Why can't I vote to close or migrate a bounty question?* might explain the reason, but I don't remember begging mods to do something like that

Comment: If it ends up being a bug... congrats on finding it, it is not like bounties are a rarely used feature so it is kind of a special moment when you happen to be the one to find it. Too bad you didn't use your lucky moment to win the lottery ;)

Comment: @Gimby, I aspire to be a penetration tester. If I find a bug and not report it, then, I don't deserve to aspire to be one :)

Comment: @Gimby Win the lottery as in unlimited bounties?

Comment: @AnnZen, I guess, they meant, I could've kept quiet about it and could've got my rep back. Not the healthiest of attitudes if they meant it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We discussed this internally. We marked it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because your situation is a bit of an edge case. We considered not allowing question deletion during the bounty grace period or not refunding the bounty if the question is deleted. Ultimately, we decided to keep system as currently designed unless and until we see your case becoming more of a common pattern.