# Two accounts, one username, their deleted question & its bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-questions, sock-puppets

I've observed what is described below on two separate occasions in the past couple of months:

1. User with 1 reputation posts a fairly complicated question
2. User with the same username but with more than 50 reputation starts a bounty on
   that question
3. Receives answer(s) but none are upvoted (because frankly they don't work)
4. After the bounty expires, first user deletes the question
5. Second user recovers their reputation

The usernames being the same could be a coincidence but it's weird that it's happened twice. However, if they indeed were the same person using two accounts, is it abuse? I'm mainly talking about the fact that the reputation was refunded to the second user once the first user deleted their question. Then again, because the questions had bounty on them, presumably many people saw those posts and saw nothing wrong with them, so I guess all is well.

P.S. The only reason I know (5) happened is that I had followed those questions during the bounty period (because I was interested in their potential answers) and was able to see their status even after they were deleted (I have since unfollowed them).

Comment: This is a loophole that seems to be only partially patched. Apparently when a question that had a bounty is deleted it is refunded to the user who awarded the bounty, with the exception if the bounty gets retained by an answer that was well-received and that if the author was the person who issued the bounty they can't self-delete. What strikes me odd here is, why does a bounty that has already expired need to be refunded?

Comment: Related: [Why was my bounty returned after I deleted the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406482/2821954) (by design in 2021)

Comment: Could be an attempt at shielding their main account from downvotes. So their only loss of rep would be the bounty.

Comment: @gre_gor At most. It looks like you get the additional attention for a bountied question at no cost if the bounty gets refunded. Smells fishy.

Comment: I see what you did there with the title... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm a fan of that movie lol

Comment: Possible usage of the bounty to block close votes? They didn't get an answer they liked by the time the bounty expired and self-deleted?  Seems like possible abuse.

Comment: It sounds like sock-puppeting to me, which is not allowed.

Comment: Which movie title is being referenced?

Comment: @abigsmall The Cook, the Thief, His Wife & Her Lover

Answer (score 33):

### My vote: Not allowed

After reviewing the rules for bounty refunds, I determined that this setup doesn't really give any material benefit in itself. In other words, if there was only one account that posted the question and started a bounty which eventually expired, deleting the question afterwards would've had the same effect of refunding the bounty. If the second account was a bit more subtle, I would say it could be an attempt to make it seem like someone else was interested in the question, but that doesn't seem too likely here.

However, it's just a really questionable use of a secondary account, which isn't really supposed to interact with the main account as a rule. Maybe there's some other shenanigans that are going on (poorly executed question ban evasion?), maybe it's just a mistake (I've seen bigger accidents from more experienced users).

Flagging (if you can) is the best option, even if you think [other people may have already flagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect).

The right way for the user to resolve this would be to [request a merge](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/).  The default mod message for sock puppets says the same thing, but ideally the merge would be requested before it comes to that.

Comment: @philipxy From what I understand of reading [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) if the bountied question gets deleted (after it has already been awarded or in between) it gets refunded to the issuer (There are a few checks in place to prevent a single user particularly the question author from abusing this). I particularly don't agree with that happening atleast with expired bounties.

Comment: @philipxy You've discovered some exceptionally poor wording on Meta SE since you *can* delete a question if it's only had expired bounties. I don't know why the system works like this, though it does seem to be on purpose that it does. If the author really decided that their question was a mistake what choice do they have but to delete it?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat & Laurel I guess the bonus return motivation may be, if the question is deleted after awarding then although the offerer got attention they didn't get to keep any benefits of the attention, so the bounty is returned (until the question is undeleted). (Although a sockpuppet bounty is against the rules.)

Comment: @philipxy that's a particularly flawed view of the bounty system though, people other than the question author can award bounties. If they got no suitable answers to award the bounty to they still didn't get any benefits, and in that case the bounty is not refunded either. I can understand refunding if the bounty is actually awarded where the consideration might be that the issuer wanted to reward a specific user, but I don't understand the motivation otherwise given expired bounties don't get refunded either.